# xcrun: error: invalid active developer path

Tags: c, macos, compiler-errors

I tried compiling a C program in the Terminal(Macbook) like this:

```
gcc Battleship.c -o Battleship
```

and I get this:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: I don't suppose you  searched for, found (on this site), and [tried **this**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig I guess that's worth a stub here as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig and it is, upvoted 500